# Recreate Minecraft's lighting

Tags: code-golf, array, matrix, physics

Minecraft has a fairly unique lighting system. Each block's light value is either one less than the brightest one surrounding it, or it is a light source itself. Your task is to write a method that takes in a 2D array of light source values, and then returns a 2D array with spread out lighting, where 0 is the minimum value.

**Examples**

```
Input1 = [
         [0, 0, 4, 0], 
         [0, 0, 0, 0], 
         [0, 2, 0, 0], 
         [0, 0, 0, 0]
        ]

Output1 = [
         [2, 3, 4, 3], 
         [1, 2, 3, 2], 
         [1, 2, 2, 1], 
         [0, 1, 1, 0]
        ]

Input2 = [
         [2, 0, 0, 3], 
         [0, 0, 0, 0], 
         [0, 0, 0, 0], 
         [0, 0, 0, 0]
        ]

Output2 = [
         [2, 1, 2, 3], 
         [1, 0, 1, 2], 
         [0, 0, 0, 1], 
         [0, 0, 0, 0]
        ]
```

**Notes**

You can assume:

1. Input will not be empty
2. The y axis will be the same length
3. All numbers will be integers; no nulls, doubles, or floats
4. All numbers will be between 0 and 15 (inclusive).

Rules:

1. Return a 2D array following the above mechanics
2. No value can be less than 0
3. If there are two highest neighbors, just subtract one from them
4. Light sources do not change, unless a surrounding block is brighter than it.
5. No standard loopholes
6. This is code golf, so shortest code wins!

Comment: I can't tell what "surrounding" means since the example seems to use all directions including diagonals in some places but not in others (the bottom left and right corners). Could you clarify?

Comment: It would be good to have some more test cases

Comment: Actually, it looks like maybe "surrounding" does not include diagonals at all?

Comment: Surrounding means the cardinal directions around it. Also, the weird instance you saw was because of two light sources. Also, I said that the highest surrounding block becomes the one to subtract from. Thank you for your interest

Comment: My bad, it was in the text

Comment: Will inputs always be square, as in the test cases?

Comment: May we take input as a flattened list, with an additional input for the width of each row?

Comment: What does 'The y axis will be the same length' mean?

Comment: @Dingus I'm pretty sure that it means that the length of each inner array will be equal to the length of the outer array, so that the 2D array always appears to be square shaped.

Comment: @engineergaming correct. It will be n * n size.

Comment: Is this really correct? as in, the diagonals are not unlit like that. if a square is a 2, the diagonal below and to the left or right, should not be 0, but 1, right? i.e., if I stand in a location in Minecraft that has dim light source, moving ahead and to the right doesn't immediately plunge me into darkness... or does it?

Comment: The diagonals of a light source will yes be less. Light source of 2 is very weak, so it only lights directly around it. Diagonals do not count to this. Take a look at this image - https://bit.ly/37Uui3Y .

Comment: The lighting system is not that unique: it's simply nearest neighbor Manhattan (L1) distance.

Comment: @CGCampbell what you see by the rendering engine does not correspond exactly with the "light level value" of a block, which is used for things like mob spawning and crop growth. If you turn off smooth lighting, you can see this better.

Comment: "If there are two highest neighbors, just subtract one from them" what does this mean?

Comment: Can we assume that the input will always be 4x4? If not, I think that some more test cases should be added to clarify that the size can be variable.

Comment: I'm not sure if following answers did assume that... but because I was not specific enough. But from now on, sure.

Comment: @qwr if a block has two 2's above, below or to the sides, and nothing higher, the block's value is 1. (subtract 1 from 2, to get 1.) iow, the 2's are not additive in any way.

Comment: What loopholes means in this context?

Comment: standard loopholes are listed at https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default

Answer (score 6):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 21 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
(⊢⌈¯1+«⌈»⌈«˘⌈»˘)⍟(≠⥊)
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgKOKKouKMiMKvMSvCq+KMiMK74oyIwqvLmOKMiMK7y5gp4o2fKOKJoOKliikKCj7ii4jin5xGwqgg4p+oCjTigL804qWK4p+oMCwwLDQsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMiwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMOKfqQo04oC/NOKliuKfqDIsMCwwLDMsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDDin6kK4p+p)

`«⌈»⌈«˘⌈»˘` computes the element-wise maximum of:

- `«` Push in 0's from the bottom
- `»` Push in 0's from the top
- `«˘` Push in 0's from right
- `»˘` Push in 0's from the left

Then substract 1 from this / add ¯1 (`¯1+`) and take the maximum with the input matrix (`⊢`).

`≠⥊` gives the number of element in the flattened matrix and `(...)⍟` iterates the function on the left that many times.

Comment: Can you add an explanation?

Comment: @Jonah added something

Comment: so bqn has a builtin for non-cycling rotation (ie, `«`)... does it also have the normal one with cycling?

Comment: @Jonah Yes rotation is the dyadic `⌽`, just as APL. BQN doesn't have infixes/windowed reduce, so stuff like `2+/\\]` <-> `1↓»⊸+` is the main use for the shifts `«` and `»`.

Answer (score 6):

## [R >=4.1](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>377</s> <s>215</s> <s>182</s> 150 bytes

```r
f=\(m,w=T,n=1:ncol(m),z=Reduce(pmax,Map(\(j){o=outer(m[p][j]-abs(n-i[j,1]),abs(n-i[j,2]),`-`);o*(o>0)},1:nrow(i<-which(p<-m>1,a=T)))))`if`(w,f(z,F),z)
```

I sure learned a lot.

Thanks to [June Choe](https://twitter.com/yjunechoe/status/1507344665514848258?s=20&t=27rn8zNl-36D-3ppsslAjw) for the `outer()` tip which enabled a significant optimisation, and then some cleanup.

Also thanks to [@pajonk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55372/pajonk) for some additional savings, use of `Map`, and for introducing me to ['attempt this online'](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=nZHPSsNAEMbxmqfY44zMQhI9iGZ705uXEk9pINs0oRvcbEg3pFZ8DS9e6sGH0qdxTVpFxD84fAwzfDDzY-bhsd1unzpb8pPn-1LMQFMvYqpFcFrn5ho00kZMi0WXF9BouaZL2cAMKrw1wnS2aEEnTZpUKZfzFdRcJRUFKdJHF7ou4xmemUMwEx_vyI1uTQ8q4v1S5UtoIq4nAUkR41tkqsygpxI2dOG240j3ciC0LVY2YBFnWtpWrSEHn5jT8ZA99jVG3__JD3_xd8JhjdP8xsEzweLp1Tl63gAVfoJ6n3j0b6g_-t9BlTDeCvdVuLvi_tev)

Comment: [154](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=nZHPaoQwEMbp1afIcQYmoLaHUsze2lsviz2psFlrWKVRcSPqPkp72R76UO3TVONuYSn9ww5fhgxfMvkxeXlt9vu31ih-_f6sRAyaOhFSKcq0egKNtBPL7LFNM6i17Ole1hBDgVVrsga8m5KmFUNPA04HQEd1EhUJl-st9DyPCvIStNVgKz9BchGna03VQR7wbpOnG6gDrhceSRHiFKtcraAjBTu6GxlwJvy4ENpkW-OxgDMtTZP3kIJLbNSVzQ77HrPv_ub7f_gHoX1m1HoY4Zlg4fLhFh3HQvknUF8dL8-G-qf_E5SCeVZ43PmHKR7_-xM) by reducing whitespace, inlining variable assignments, using `Map` instead of `lapply` and renaming the main function.

Comment: [150](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=nZHPSsRADMbx2qeYYwIZaKsHkY43vXlZ6qktbLd22ClOW7pT2u6DePGyHnwofRpnp7vCIv7B8BESPkh-JM8v3W732hvJL9-epEhB0yBiqkVwVRfNI2ikrViUD31RQqvzke7yFlKosOlN2UFNNaUw0oR7E3TSZkmV8Xy1gZGrpKIgQ9dNrgszJB-R7PCuGUBFfFirYg1txPV1QDHuY6nkEgaSsKVbux1nuvczoU25MQGLONO56dQIBfjErC5c9tjXmH3_Jz_8xT8I3Rqr1WTRmWDx4v4GPc9BhSdQnxPP_w31R_87KAnzrfBYhYcrHn_9AQ) actually

Comment: Still [150](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=nZHPSsNAEMbxmqfY44zMQhI9iGZ705uXEk9pINs0oRvcbEg3pFZ8DS9e6sGH0qdxTVpFxD84fAwzfDDzY-bhsd1unzpb8pPn-1LMQFMvYqpFcFrn5ho00kZMi0WXF9BouaZL2cAMKrw1wnS2aEEnTZpUKZfzFdRcJRUFKdJHF7ou4xmemUMwEx_vyI1uTQ8q4v1S5UtoIq4nAUkR41tkqsygpxI2dOG240j3ciC0LVY2YBFnWtpWrSEHn5jT8ZA99jVG3__JD3_xd8JhjdP8xsEzweLp1Tl63gAVfoJ6n3j0b6g_-t9BlTDeCvdVuLvi_tev) if I use an alternative `outer` formulation from [here](https://twitter.com/mjskay/status/1507814146309558274?s=20&t=7Ziq5YLR6H9jrs9VUfuzVQ). I wasn't aware of ATO - thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>99 94</s>  93 bytes

Modifies the input matrix in-place.

```javascript
m=>{for(d=64;d--;m.map((r,y)=>r.map((v,x)=>r[x]=(q=~-(m[y+D%2]||0)[x+~-D%2])>v?q:v)))D=d%4-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rY1dC4IwFIbv9yt2I@3gJsusi2J2479YXkhqKG4rC1H6@OtLiyiCICI4nMPD4X2fMmmS/boutgemTZrZXFglwmNuapKKWbBIGVsoTyVbQmragQjrOzS0HUC2sSA7cWFEyc6NHD8@nTjI1r2wASBslrt5AwCRSJ2Ajc82JwoLLBHGklPcT9DvmD6Zv7L/xo8/igGtjd6bKvMqsyHKK02hyWilR4BdfLsIvbj8R3by0cX/5fqie/qDC@wV)

#### Commented

```javascript
m => {                   // m[] = input matrix
  for(                   // repeat 64 times,
    d = 64;              // using d as a counter:
    d--;                 //
    m.map((r, y) =>      //   for each row r[] at position y in m[]:
      r.map((v, x) =>    //     for each value v at position x in r[]:
        r[x] = (         //       update r[x]:
          q =            //         q is the value of the neighbor cell
          ~-(            //         located at m[y + dy][x + dx],
            m[y + D % 2] //         using D as the current direction
            || 0         //         (-1 = North, 0 = West, 1 = South,
          )[x + ~-D % 2] //         2 = East), minus 1
        ) > v ? q        //         keep the maximum of q and the
              : v        //         current value v
      )                  //     end of inner map()
    )                    //   end of outer map()
  ) D = d % 4 - 1        //   set D to (d mod 4) - 1
}                        // implicit end of for()
```

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 24 bytes

```
Xz,G@+&fh]&1ZP-TYaX>GZye
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P6JKx91BWy0tI1bNMCpANyQyMcLOPaoy9f//aAMFAwUTBQNrBQMIBDGMYAwwjAUA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8D@iSsfdQVstLSNWzTAqQDckMjHCzj2qMvW/QXKES1RFyP9oAwUDBRMFA2sFAwgEMYxgDDCM5YoGCygYoyhCZcQCAA).

#### Explanation

```
Xz       % Implicit input. Get nonzeros as a column vector (*)
,        % Do twice
  G      %   Push input
  @      %   Push iteration index: 0 or 1
  +      %   Add, element-wise
  &f     %   Two-output find: gives row and column indices of nonzeros
  h      %   Concatenate horizontally. Gives a 2-row matrix where each
         %   row contains the coordinates of nonzeros (first iteration)
         %   or of all entries (second iteration)
]        % End
&1ZP     % Cityblock distance between rows
-        % Subtract from (*), element-wise with broadcast
TYa      % Extend with two rows of zeros. This serves two purposes:
         % making sure that the maximum of each row is at least 0; and
         % making sure that each column has more than 1 entry, so that
         % the following function (maximum) operates along the first
         % dimension (compute maximum of each column)
X>       % Maximum along the first (non-singleton) dimension (**)
GZy      % Push input. Size
e        % Reshape (**) with the specified size. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 5):

## C(gcc) <strike>230</strike> <strike>227</strike> <strike>220</strike> <strike>172</strike> <strike>171</strike> <strike>128</strike> 97 bytes

smaller thanks to @Muskovets an @engineergaming, and now @ceilingcat

```c
i,j;f(n,x,y)int*n;{for(i=x*y;i--;)for(j=x*y;j--;n[j]=fmax(n[j],n[i]-abs(i%x-j%x)-abs(i/x-j/x)));}
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##hVBBboMwELzzilWqSLZjSppGvRj6kZSDYwIYEacC2hpFfL10bSKFpJUqWaud8eysPSoslBoftFH1R3aAuO0yfXosX4MbqtZ75EbNK5ETwy3vqTYdM@KcnxqiE8t6ocNQUAcrDyuEZlelSX6UlriOm51OQ7lviV7asFpaOoEIQWQppWIY0RWOUhviGtkUioMqZcOYA58UzgHAe4OXOVnsD4U2b2ZBRYBsxLC4qS@ddSUksBUXojzoouzmjGya3dNLitR5zQHP1te7s/lNDs6BRcG/q55vVm38qj@X3NvjWE5wiE/m/GI5/RHTBZ9Mn6wF9PF0h91qNUUzk1gnsbF3weaquAa4zDgsuH@ihRX0zItTKrxuCObaKWfHBsP4rfJaFu0Y1scf)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer! I think you can save a few bytes by removing some spaces in the argument list.

Comment: [199 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY3BCsIwEER/xUsh2WypZ9foh4iHGqpuWpMQK6aUfnts7UW8DLx5A2PKmzE5s@s3cBUOEw7okdFiixGDnAU4BI8QaPT6UXedNyLBIIn1lt537hrB@6UY/YnPc8dK0bRI@z9oNQinWP4Yu5qgvbIUdVvWl6fgIpW2SHKFaoYqSYKgBYRDlEcIu0j2e7NEbPpXdBtPU84f) by abusing parameter declarations

Comment: [172 bytes](https://tio.run/##fU/LbsIwELzzFSsqJL8oKXCqMf2QNIcQElgr2MgkalCUb083iRD0Usna8Y5ndsfZ8pRl/Ru6rKyPOexu1RH9@3k/@0OVeCCuF16hiZRVQYuCOdWoO0dXCadbby5pWfqMNeLO9c8Zy5zhbmh8jFImJtJoLNXXp/ZJ2IkIxsWYLNPDjeGiWdpFw6dmRc2q4drHNjFsqPvAvwb8DNpKqTscSsirOjjwuuspGFxSdGy4oILsnAYQIuPQzgCugeiCzQ/5Cd23m3NN5Kh017qKP9YJGGi3CqL/T/fwCV9X5CRXwcYZCsi9GecWPsAYw9JzpAl2sCGQcgrzosBJgaTYEjwVz8iLo4K5gmlfjCDBim0yLgLoZq/Sx8cGtgh5ziYTcV3/Cw "C (gcc) – Try It Online") by editing @engineergaming's

Comment: [104 bytes](https://tio.run/##hVDLboMwELzzFatUSNgxJU2jHmpIPyTlwCPAotSpHNoaRXw7XZtIeVWqZC0749lZM0VYF8X4gKrYfZVbiA9difvHZu1dUTvMiRtRtELLKlDCiJ6h6riSx2qvA0wM7yWGoWQWtg62FupEbTANs/wQoG/C1jdsAhGByDChNm2a2LLWb/bzquUwkjV8ZKgC22S6LgQUTaY5t@CbwdED@NR0WQWzfFujelczJj1iI07FTv1g2TWQwEqeiGaLddNdMpnWm6eXlKjjQgCdlas3Z3lPDtaBR96/q56vVi3dqj@X3NrTWBXQkJjMxcly@keKGFwyfbKQ0MfTHXXz@RTNhcRYiYmdCzVnxTlAvxQwE@6JBubQcydOmXS6wbvUTjlb1hvGXw) if you modify the array in place (not sure if that's allowed but a couple answers do that)

Comment: [89 bytes](https://tio.run/##dVDBboMwDL3zFRYTUgLJaKeoF8p@hHEIoaFBkE7QTSDEr485cGi3bpJl@b1nP9lWvFJqeTJWNR/lCY79tTSX5/Or94NqTIHcYlidaGLsNbR00peOmHR/SAznCXWodqhGZLM6T3UrB@IqZjOTc1n0xASC14GgG4gRxIJSmswLekIrjXXmILtKMVBn2YWhA58UJg/gvUNRE784Vca@WZ8mHrLbQJftDzmkMO0YYIg1/4qXR3JGizh@MPlz/N@Y1z00QYNtJfwFrIeM6S6B8SgwRdF2xJ06OHVw6nBTb2cGJQOfrWsNEMEYihztXcfs3fdtn3CsNy9fSjey6hfetN8) if you assume the array is 4x4 (which OP allowed in comments)

Comment: Managed to merge the two loops and got [literally no savings](https://tio.run/##dVDRaoQwEHzPVyxXBKOxnkV8aLT9EOtDjBcvorHEa1HEX69N9OGuvRaWJTszO@yEBzXn64NUvP2oTpAOl0r2j@cX9ANqZWmwVZKGCleqi6fwLHrt0iaNEqrypshEx0ZX5bIIWDm40omDxonxPoRmCGNMrBAT6fvECLIowa/Pje9juqzGEzomlTUHpmtOgJ@Z9jw7fGKYEcC7NqRwD@WplupNHTBFKAwB9hWdR0kBGcxHAqbirf@qp3twMSZ3Fn8u/1u7hXCNAd6fvYYtyJQdKUxpbJqJuYW4YUfLjpYdr@w1plMROJDtrBF8mLy4MPZWsaBb3f4TFkXL@sVFy@phDdruGw), maybe someone will be able to golf this down further?

Comment: Building on [engineer gaming](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92496/engineer-gaming) [88 bytes](https://tio.run/##dVDRboMwDHznKywmpASS0VUZLyn7EdaHkDY0CNIJugmE@PUxA5ParZtkWfbd@WRb80Lr6cE6Xb0fjrBrLwd7fjy9eD@gyuaITZaV0hDrLqGjgzk3xKbb50RaziV1WblPTa064jIbPyV7rvKWzFUgeBkI@t0n2MWCMtSnNkAdleOEllAr62ZvUE2hGeiTasJwbj4oDB7AW4OkIX5@LKx7dT6VHqLrQJOhEaQwbBhgiCX/iu09OKJFHN@Z/Dn@b4zLHoagwboSPgaWQ/p0I6HfCUxRtB5xw3Yz281sd2WvZwYHBj5b1uoggj4U@KlFM3q3uvUTM@qN06c2lSraiVf1Fw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>100</s> <s>98</s>  94 bytes

```javascript
A=Math.abs
f=(a,i,j)=>a.map((r,y)=>r.map((c,x)=>1/i?t=t>(u=c-A(i-y)-A(j-x))?t:u:f(t=a,y,x)|t))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3BCoJAEIbvPoXHWZg1i07CKj5ATyAepk1rxVzRMRR6dxsIu1TDMD/fxw/T0INGO7iedecv1brm5kR8i@g8BrUBQoeNMilFd@oBBlwEhjdYnAX2O5ex4RQmY3UOTi9KotGzUhknU1IDG8JFuk9WarW@G31bRa2/Qg1FEG5TxBjKHuWWGH75@Jc//PFb/2NL@fwC)

-4 byte from ophact

Comment: I was posting an answer the exact instant you posted this :|

Comment: Use `Math.abs` for absolute value (assign `A` directly to the function) to save bytes

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) with [numpy](https://numpy.org/), 93 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,n=0:f(rot90(fmax(a,r_[a[1:],a[-1:]]-1)),n+1)if n<len(a)*4else a
from numpy import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcXBCgIhEADQe1/h0dlmQdkuLe2XiMREDgk6ihm0X297jXd4de@vIssYvCXKjycpQtnMyrqVfjWaM301Ybs7cnb1SG4@8rMFQDlbiKzkloJogukS0jsoOnErWckn113FXEvr06gtStesnTN48Pj34j3A@AE)

Each iteration spreads light upwards, then rotates the array by 90 degrees.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>28</sup> 27 bytes

```
(>./@,((,-)=1 2)|.!.0<:)^:_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/Nez09B10NDR0dDVtDRWMNGv0FPUMbKw046zi/2ty@TnpKcSCVcQbaoMVKVvBVcVypSZn5CukKZgAoQrQTAMgbaAAZhhAGEYwBhhC1Kuro@qDqDFG0YfK@A8A)

Consider input:

```
0 0 4 0
0 0 0 0
0 2 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

- `(,-)=1 2)` 4 directions of movement:

  ```
   1  0
   0  1
  _1  0
   0 _1
  ```
- `|.!.0<:` Rotate the input minus 1 in those directions:

  ```
  _1 _1 _1 _1
  _1  1 _1 _1
  _1 _1 _1 _1
   0  0  0  0

  _1  3 _1  0
  _1 _1 _1  0
   1 _1 _1  0
  _1 _1 _1  0

   0  0  0  0
  _1 _1  3 _1
  _1 _1 _1 _1
  _1  1 _1 _1

   0 _1 _1  3
   0 _1 _1 _1
   0 _1  1 _1
   0 _1 _1 _1
  ```
- `>./@,` Prepend input and max reduce the 5 "planes":

  ```
  0 3 4 3
  0 1 3 0
  1 2 1 0
  0 1 0 0
  ```
- `(...)^:_` Repeat that process until a fixed point:

  ```
  2 3 4 3
  1 2 3 2
  1 2 2 1
  0 1 1 0
  ```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>207</s> 205 bytes

Once I first saw this challenge posted, I started having some ideas for python solutions bouncing around in my head. This solution turned out to be way longer than I would have hoped, but I did find away to do this without `numpy`, which the other python solution uses:

```python
f=lambda x:[[eval(f"max(max({i*'x[i-1][j],'}{j*'x[i][j-1],'}{~i%len(x)*'x[i+1][j],'}{~j%len(x)*'x[i][j+1],'})-1,x[i][j])")for j in range(len(x))]for i in range(len(x))]
g=lambda x:x if f(x)==x else g(f(x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7RCoMgFIbv9xSHYKRlsOhu0JOIF46pU8yixXDEenWnBW1jHA6H7@P/4QzP6da7JgTZWt5drhz8mVLx4BbJrOMepZ11kXuqq5pRw0j@ms3KkaJKvOijFQ55vPpyzy3m20dbrnlc1WRjhjMs@xEMaAcjd0qgrYBZ0vpfH9TnUQ9agoy6bT0IexegUEIc9rJClJ5IHEZ@bsMYPsMwajehQuPwBg)

I wanted to be able to fit this into one lambda, but I simply couldn't seem to get the conditional to work, so `g(x)` is the function that is actually called to get the result. The main bulk of the code is in the giant `eval()` statement, which basically calculates the highest adjacent block, subtracts 1 from that, and takes the the max of that and the blocks current value. The rest of the code just iterates that over each block, and then recursively does that until all light levels have been calculated.

Comment: you can save 2 bytes by changing `f(x)if f(x)==x` to `x if f(x)==x`

Comment: Oh good one @patcharalimtrairat, I cant believe i missed that

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 107 bytes

```
r x=[0..length x-1]
f a=let(w,h)=(r$head a,r a)in[[maximum[a!!y!!x-abs(x-j)-abs(y-i)|x<-w,y<-h]|j<-w]|i<-h]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboWN7OLFCpsow309HJS89JLMhQqdA1judIUEm1zUks0ynUyNG01ilQyUhNTFBJ1ihQSNTPzoqNzEysyc0tzoxMVFSsVFSt0E5OKNSp0szTBjErdTM2aChvdcp1KG92M2JosIDO2JhPEhlgJtRnmAgA)

Comment: [101 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboWN1OLFCpsow309HJS89JLMhQqdA1judIUEmvKbXSLVDJSE1MUEnUygGyFRNvo6NzEiszc0tzoREXFSkXFCt3EpGKNCt0sTTCjUjdTs6bCRrdcp9JGNyO2JgvIjK3JBLGhlnnmJmbmKdgqFBRl5pUoqCikKURHG-goAJEJkIzVUYDyDBA8IxQeTA5qIMwXAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 22 bytes

```
ＩＥθＥι⌈Ｅθ⌈Ｅν⁻π⁺↔⁻ξκ↔⁻ρμ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzexQKNQRwFEZYKoiszc0lyEKIKbB@Rm5pUWaxToKATkAGnHpOL8nNKSVA2IcIWOQrampo4CmnCRjkKuJhKw/v8/OjraSEfBAIyMY3UUuBQUog1gAgZECMTG/tctywEA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Same algorithm as @alephalpha's PARI/GP answer.

```
 ＥθＥι                   Map over input array
      Ｅθ Ｅν             Map over input array
            π           Innermost value
           ⁻            Subtract
              ↔⁻ξκ      Absolute row difference
             ⁺          Plus
                  ↔⁻ρμ  Absolute column difference
     ⌈  ⌈               Take the maximum
Ｉ                       Cast to string
                        Implicitly print
```

Note that Charcoal's default I/O format is rather ugly so I've also written a 26-byte prettier version which unfortunately only works up to 9:

```
ＷＳ⊞υιＥυ⭆ι⌈Ｅυ⌈Ｅν⁻π⁺↔⁻ξκ↔⁻ρμ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYpBCsIwEEX3OcUsJzDCIO66cumiEPAEsRQTTNKQJrW3jylVFP9m/nvzB6PTMGlX69NYNwJeQiz5mpMNd5QSVJkNFgIrO6GazNjruIl9soEl6PVqffGf3y@GhjaUGSOBcu2eb/PkSh5x1yvBQ0qCP50IvPymq5X5xIJbBB/53ephcS8) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 73 bytes

```
m->matrix(#m~,#m,i,j,vecmax(matrix(#m~,#m,k,l,m[k,l]-abs(k-i)-abs(l-j))))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWNz1zde1yE0uKMis0lHPrdJRzdTJ1snTKUpNzEys0UCWydXJ0cqOBZKxuYlKxRrZupiaYkaObpQkEUAPbEgsKcio1chV07RQKijLzSoBMJRBHSSFNI1dTU0chOtpARwGITICktQKEbQBjGyGxoSgWqMUIxjPG0IGFHRsLdc2CBRAaAA)

\$output[i,j]=\underset{k,l}\max(input[k,l]-|k-i|-|l-j|)\$

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>22</s> 21 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Δ<U4FøíXøíDUćaª‚øεø€à
```

Port of [*@Jonah*'s J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/245462/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3BSbUBO3wzsOr40AES6hR9oTD6161DDr8I5zWw/veNS05vCC//@jow10DHRMdAxidcAsAyjLCM6CiMUCAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaCkU3lotw6Xkn9pCZy/8v@5KTahh9aZuB3ecXhtBIhwCT3Snnho1aOGWYd3nNt6eMejpjWHF/yvra0Faj60zf5/dHS0gY6BjomOQawOmGUAZRnBWRCxWB2F6GiwoI4xmlJ0VmwsAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Δ           # Loop until the result no longer changes:
 <          #  Decrease each value in the matrix by 1
            #  (which will be the implicit input-matrix in the first iteration)
  U         #  Pop and store it in variable `X`
 4F         #  Loop 4 times:
   øí       #   Rotate the matrix once clockwise:
   ø        #    Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
    í       #    Reverse each inner row
            #   (which will be the implicit input-matrix in the first iteration)
   X        #   Push matrix `X`
    øí      #   Rotate it once clockwise as well
      DU    #   Store a copy as new value for `X`
        ć   #   Extract head; pop remainder-matrix and first row separated
         a  #   Convert all values in this row to 0 (with an is_letter check)
          ª #   Append this list of 0s as trailing row
   ‚øεø€à   #   Reduce the two matrices by maximum:
   ‚        #    Pair the two matrices together
    ø       #    Zip/transpose; creating pair of rows
     εø     #    Zip/transpose each inner pair of rows to pair of cell-values
       €à   #    Leave the maximum of each inner-most pair of cell-values
            # (after which the resulting matrix is output implicitly)
```